# Import mysqldump fails with ERROR 1005

Tags: mysql

On my host are two databases with different versions. I am trying to import the old version to the newer one with the following command:

```
mysql --user=lamp -p --host=localhost databasename < dumbfile.sql
```

> ERROR 1005 (HY000) at line 76: Can't create table 'uni.tablename' (errno: 150)

The import fails with ERROR 1005. How could it be that my dump of the database is inconsistent? Do I have to delete the old database?

Answer (score -1):

```
mysql -u lamp -h localhost -p password newdatabase < dumbfile.sql
```

> You can try it after create new database.